# ng-disabled not working in button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm learning angular stuffs and got stuck up in `ng-disabled` directive. Below is my code.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app>

<body>
  <input type="text" ng-model="myName" ng-change="txtEnable()" />
  <span>{{ (myName.length % 2) === 0 }}</span>
  <button ng-disabled="{{ (myName.length % 2) === 0 }}">button</button>
</body>

</html>
```

when i change the value in text, the span element get updated but the button doesn't. what i did wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Got it!** The problem is with curly braces `{{}}`.

Curly braces(`{{}}`) to bind expressions to elements is built-in Angular markup.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app>

<body>
  <input type="text" ng-model="myName" ng-change="txtEnable()" />
  <span>{{ (myName.length % 2) === 0 }}</span>
  <button ng-disabled="(myName.length % 2) === 0">button</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: great that you find the solution. But the version of angular you are using is very very old. Better to start learning angular2. to setup your environment you can use angular-cli. good luck!

Comment: @Extranion yet to start!